# live search in symfony4 using ajax+js

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

i want to implement a live search under symfony 4 but im stuck.
i hope your help friends.

**my controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/search", name="search")
 */
 public function searchAction(Request $request){
    $user = new User();

         $searchTerm = $request->query->get('search');        
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $results = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $searchTerm]);
         //$results = $query->getResult();

         $content = $this->renderView('search.html.twig', [
            'res' => $results,
            'val' => $searchTerm

]);

$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData(array('list' => $content));
return $response;
         }
```

**my script ajax**
this my ajax script

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{ path('search') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {search: input},
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
               $('.example-wrapper').replaceWith(response);
               //$('.example-wrapper').load("{{ path('search') }}?search="+ $search.val());
                console.log(response);
                 },
        error: function (response) {
               console.log(response);
                   }
      });
```

***search.html.twig***

```
    <form class="example-wrapper" role="search" method="post" action="{{ path('search') }}">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" value="{{ val }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="sub">search</button>
    </div>
    </form>

    <div class="example-wrapper">
    {% for result in res %}
    <p style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">{{ result.fullname }}</p>
    <p style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">{{ result.username }}</p>
    <p style="display:inline-block;width:300px;">{{ result.email }}</p>
    <p style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">{{ result.roles[0] }}</p> 
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

the search page looks like that i cant see the form unless take off ajax script

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. :) Personally I'd do something like this.

Action function:

```
/**
 * Search action.
 * @Route("/search/{search}", name="search")
 * @param  Request               $request Request instance
 * @param  string                $search  Search term
 * @return Response|JsonResponse          Response instance
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request, string $search)
{
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->render("search.html.twig");
    }

    if (!$searchTerm = trim($request->query->get("search", $search))) {
        return new JsonResponse(["error" => "Search term not specified."], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if (!($results = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneByEmail($searchTerm))) {
        return new JsonResponse(["error" => "No results found."], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new JsonResponse([
        "html" => $this->renderView("search.ajax.twig", ["results" => $results]),
    ]);
}
```

Your `search.html.twig` should not contain the for loop with the results, but instead should just be this instead of the for loop:

```
<form id="search-form" class="example-wrapper" role="search" method="get" action="{{ path('search') }}">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="sub">search</button>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="search-results" class="example-wrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#search-form').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#search-results').html("");

        $.get("{{ path('search') }}/" + input, function(data, textStatus, xhr){

            if ("object" !== typeof data || null === data) {
                alert("Unexpected response from server.");
                return;
            }

            if (!data.hasOwnProperty("html") || typeof data.html != "string" || (data.html = data.html.trim()).length < 1) {
                alert("Empty response from server.");
                return;
            }

            $('#search-results').html(data.html);

        }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){

            var error = "Unknown error occurred.";
            if ("object" === typeof xhr && null !== xhr && xhr.hasOwnProperty("responseJSON") && "object" === typeof xhr.responseJSON && xhr.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty("error") && "string" === typeof xhr.responseJSON.error && xhr.responseJSON.error.trim().length >= 1) {
                error = xhr.responseJSON.error.trim();
            } else if ("string" === typeof errorThrown && errorThrown.trim().length >= 1) {
                error = errorThrown.trim();
            }

            alert(error);

        });

    });

});

--></script>
```

You should then have `search.ajax.html` in the same folder as `search.html.twig` to contain the results loop. This should consist of only this:

```
{% if results is defined and results is iterable and results|length >= 1 %}
    {% for result in results %}
        <p style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">{{ result.fullname }}</p>
        <p style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">{{ result.username }}</p>
        <p style="display:inline-block;width:300px;">{{ result.email }}</p>
        <p style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">{{ result.roles[0] }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: hey adambean thank you so much for your help but still there problems :

Comment: (1/4) ResourceNotFoundException 
 (2/4) NotFoundHttpException
 No route found for "GET /search"
 (3/4) Error
 Class 'App\Controller\ExceptionController' not found
 (4/4) InvalidArgumentException
 Controller "App\Controller\ExceptionController" does neither exist as service nor as class
please if you have any idea let me know else send me ur email i want ask you ?

Comment: ResourceNotFoundException: That'll be because "search.html.twig" is missing or "search.ajax.twig" is missing.

Comment: NotFoundHttpException: Change `public function searchAction(Request $request, string $search)` to `public function searchAction(Request $request, string $search = null)`

Comment: I'd need line numbers for the other two issues.

Comment: No, that is against the Stack Exchange ethos of community discussion. Please keep this open for public debate and contribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182652/discussion-between-younes-oulkaid-and-adambean).

Comment: hey yes i did as you see in shot screens above there is all my pages and the errorrs too